# EntityFramework/LINQ: filter a hierarchical list

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I need to filter a hierarchical list like:

- Folder 1
- Folder 2

  - Document 1
  - Document 2
  - Folder 4

    - Document 3
    - Document 4
- Folder 3

  - Document

Each folder has folders and/or documents. Each document has a `Status` enum.
How can i get all empty Folders or with documents where the status from the document is on "Deleted"?

```
var folders = from f in context.Folders
              // where f.Documents.All( d => d.Status == DocumentStatus.Deleted )
              select f;
```

Lazy loading is enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
Folders.Where(folder => folder.Documents.Any(document => document.Status == DocumentStatus.Deleted));
```

---

Unfortunately you have a more complex structure, the above linq statement will work only of folders have documents and not other folders.

To do what you want to do you will have to define a Predicate manually and filter with that, because in the case that a folder has children which are folders themselves, you have to recursively call the filter method to see if the condition is true.

Comment: I will define a Predicate manually because it's a complex structure.